UK PhD application Advice for a Socially Awkward Person
I am a UK Life Science Mres student whose program just started and is trying to apply for 2025 PhD studentships. How should I interact with supervisors? I have very bad social cues/skills. How do similar people navigate this?

When emailing a potential PhD supervisor for an advertised pre-designed project, do I still have to include my CV and credentials? (I see this as a recommendation for emailing prospective supervisors)
How should I go about asking my current supervisor naturally if there is any internal DTPs/funding and to take me as a PhD student? (I saw that some people do this and it turned out well for them, but I find it so hard to bring this up, especially since I’m so new in her lab)


There is nothing particularly unusual about your situation. Lots of academics are (or started out) very introverted and/or "on the spectrum". You do what anyone would do. See the answer for UK for advice on applying to doctoral programs.
As for the social awkwardness, note that it can be overcome with will and with practice. Seeing a professional about it and techniques to overcome it is advised. I know plenty of such folks at the top ranks of academia. Some are amazing public speakers, for example. Good luck.

thank you for your response :)

To directly answer your questions:

Yes, a would include a CV when you are approaching a supervisor even for a pre-designed project. The person you address may not look at them, but it doesn't inconvenience them for those materials to be present and they may want took at them.

With regards to your current supervisor, if you find bringing up the issue in person too awkward, there is nothing wrong with emailing them. It is possible that are well aware of your difficulty with social interaction (unless your mark is very good). Either way when looking for a supervisor,  you want someone you can work with.  If they can't interaction that emailing may be easier for you,  perhaps they are not the right supervisor. However, most supervisors will understand.



thank you so much ^^
